# User Home directly from shell_exec in PHP running on Apache

Tags: php, apache, apache-modules

I have the following snippet of code in a PHP file:

```
echo `whoami;cd;pwd`;
```

When I run this script from the command line (lets call this test.php), `php test.php`, I get the following output:

```
rohit /home/rohit
```

When I run this over the browser, I get:

```
rohit /var/www/html
```

I enabled UserDir mod on my apache configuration and apache is running as the user `rohit` but I can't get this to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the following in a PHP file worked for me.

```
putenv('HOME='. PATH_TO_HOME);
```